# Is it possible to derive the type and constructors of an ADT using a first-class description?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, agda, idris, morte

Suppose that, to describe tree-like algebraic data types, we use the following type, `Data`:

```
∀(D : *) →
∀(S : *) →
∀(P : *) →
∀(data : S → D) →
∀(add : P → S → S) →
∀(zer : S) →
∀(mul : (D → D) → P → P) →
∀(one : P) →
D
```

This is, for example, the type `List Nat`:

```
λ(D : *) →
λ(S : *) →
λ(P : *) →
λ(data : S → D) →
λ(add : P → S → S) →
λ(zer : S) →
λ(mul : (D → D) → P → P) →
λ(one : P) →
-- data List Nat =
data 
  -- Cons
  (add
    -- Nat
    (mul (λ(list : D) → 
      -- data Nat =
      data 
        -- Succ Nat
        (add (mul (λ(nat : D) → nat) one)
        -- Zero
        (add one zer)))
    -- List Nat
    (mul (λ(list : D) → list) one))
  -- Nil
  (add one zer))
```

Now, if we define `Data.type` as:

```
λ (type : #Data ) ->
type ? ? ?
(λ (data:?) -> ∀ (a:?) -> (data a))
(λ (ctorType: ?) -> λ (rest:?) -> ∀ (a:?) -> ∀ (ctor:(ctorType a)) -> (rest a))
(∀ (a:?) -> a)
(λ (fieldType: ?) -> λ (rest:?) -> ∀ (a:?) -> ∀ (field:(fieldType a)) -> (rest a))
(∀ (a:?) -> a)
```

And we apply it to `List Nat`, ignoring type errors, that normalizes to the type of church-encoded lists of nats, which is `∀(a:*) -> (((∀ (a:*) -> ((a -> a) -> a -> a)) -> a -> a) -> a -> a`. I'd like to know:

1. Is it possible to type the `Data.type` term?
2. If not, is there any way to achieve similar effect, using a different strategy?

Comment: Perhaps it is just my unfamiliarity with the syntax (what is `type : #Data`? What is `Data` vs. `#Data`. etc.) but it seems you want a function which produces a type whose terms are the inhabitants of that datatype, according to some encoding - such a function would simply have type `Data -> *`. Anyways, the term you wrote for `List Nat` can't possibly mean what you think it means - you have both `mul (λ(list : D) ..` and `mul (λ(nat : D) ..` - you can't possible distinguish such uses of a lambda bound variable. Then it must be that `List` and `Nat` are identical types?

Comment: @user2407038 #Data just inlines the `Data` type I defined earlier.

Comment: @user2407038 no, that function is used to mark the transition between different datatypes... `λ (self:D) -> self`, aka `id`, means it is a direct recursive field (both cases here, Nat and List)... `λ (self:D) -> parent`, aka `const parent`, means it is a recursive field, but it jumps back to a parent type, not to itself (think of `Tree (List Int)`)... `λ (x:D) -> data ...` means it isn't a recursive field, but the beginning of another instead. It is useful for generics, you call that function with the recursive bits and it puts them in the right places on the derived generic normal form.

Comment: The two terms `mul (λ(nat : D) → nat) one` and `mul (λ(list : D) → list) one` are identical. You can't supply a function `mul` which makes identical applications of it into different outputs - this is literally the definition of a function (equal inputs to equal outputs). The fact that the two terms are used in different contexts in a larger term doesn't matter. I think you wan't something like `mul (\nat -> add one nat)`, similarly for lists.

Comment: @user2407038 you don't get it. You supply it with the recursive constructors of the currently parsed type. So the first receives nat, because it is on the context of nat, and the second receives list, because it is on the context of list. The function is supposed to return the argument it received, **except** if it isn't a recursive field. I know it is correct since I've been using it on the untyped lambda calculus for months and it is the simplest way I found to derive all kinds of generic functions based on descriptions, which ranges from constructors to functor, foldable and even zipWith...

Comment: You say all of this as if `mul`, `data`, etc. are already algebraic constructors of some type, with an elimination principle. The only way for you to eliminate a `Data` (i.e. write a function `Data -> Anything`) is to apply the `x : Data` to a *specific* `D : *` and give functions for that specific type - but terms of type `Data` must (clearly) be parametric in `D`. None of those functions consume a `D` so a function `D -> D` is either `id` or `const e` for some `e : D`. ....

Comment: ... I think this is what you mean by "The function is supposed to return the argument it received, except if it isn't a recursive field." But clearly you cannot distinguish between the functions `\x -> x` and `\_ -> e` and I don't even think it is possible to prove (in the host language) that these are the only two functions which can be passed to `mul` inside `d : Data`. And finally, I agree that "I don't get it" - could you include a formal semantics (in the metatheory) for such a type `Data`? What precisely does every 'field' indicate? How precisely can they be used? Can that be enforced?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying... that is exactly what I said, though, it is either `id` or `const k`... that is what it is for. I think it is really hard to explain with words, so take a look on the [implementation](http://lpaste.net/344938) of a generic constructor deriver for a similar encoding on the untyped λ-calculus. It works for arbitrary ADTs and needs that `d:Data` thing. I was trying to replicate that on Morte, but I'm having trouble figuring out the types... and that is all that the question was about. Sorry if I don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: Just think about it, you want to derive a generic constructor function from an arbitrary datatype specification... take the church encoding for Nat, the first ctor is `(λ x . λ s . λ n . (s (x s z)))`... notice that the first field of the first ctor is `x s z`... in order to achieve that, you must apply to `x` to `s z`... so you call that function we're debating with `(x -> (x s z))`. What if that field isn't a recursive field, but "something else" (`const somethingElse`)? Then you still apply it to `(x -> (x s z))`, but it will overwrite `s z` with the proper constructors of "something else".

Comment: Oh wait, if you are talking specifically about the type `D -> D`, I have no idea if that is right... the question is exactly whether it is possible to type those previously untyped terms correctly... I didn't think much about the types...

Comment: Are the `∀(a : ?) → a` arguments supposed to be `λ(a : ?) → a` instead?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez now that you pointed it, probably...